# Wildcard Subdomains and Custom Domain Names

Tags: nginx, subdomain, cloudflare, wildcard-subdomain

I have some questions regarding Nginx configuration with wildcard subdomains, and then how custom domains come into the picture. Here is my situation.

Let's say I own the site `awesome.com`. When a user signs up for my site, they automatically get a subdomain. So user **Steve** could navigate to his homepage via `steve.awesome.com`. To accomplish this, create a wildcard subdomain CNAME record. Internally, I want the application to treat this as `awesome.com/users/steve`. After viewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322826/nginx-rewrite-without-change-url), I believe I should be able to rewrite the route to my desired result, without actually changing what the URL displays in the browser.

Now, I want to allow Steve to set up his own custom domain. Let's say Steve owns the domain `iamsteve.com`. Steve could then point his domain, to his subdomain `steve.awesome.com`.

My main question is, when a request is made to `iamsteve.com`, will my Nginx server receive the request as `steve.awesome.com`, thus allowing the rewrite logic to still work correctly? Or will it actually receive the request as `iamsteve.com`?

Answer (score 1):

The web browser sends whatever hostname is in the URL for the requested resource in the `Host` header.

Eg, user navigates to `http://foo.example/bar`, the header will be `Host: foo.example`. The name resolution process does not affect this.

Comment: @Andrew Backes So, to achieve what you want, you may checkout the [map directive](http://nginx.org/r/map).